# Gerar números aleatórios e somá-los

Tags: python

Eu gostava de conseguir fazer o script gerar "**n**" números(até aí está tudo feito como podem ver no código abaixo) e somá-los.

```
import random

n = 2

total = (random.randint(1, 100), n)

print total
```

Agora só falta somar esses "n" numeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isso que você precisa?

```
import random

n = 2

total = random.randint(1, 100) + n

print total
```

Se você precisa randomizar mais de 1 número e somar todos os números gerados, pode fazer desta forma:

```
import random

total = 0;

for i in xrange(0, 2):
    numeroGerado = random.randint(1, 100)
    print numeroGerado
    total += numeroGerado

print total
```

Comment: Qual é a lógica em somar o valor de `n` com o número aleatório no primeiro código?

Answer (score 3):

Para gerar **n** números aleatórios, utilize [geradores](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
numbers = (random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n))
```

> **Nota:** Se a lista de números for utilizada para mais coisas além de apenas de calcular a soma, não utilize gerador, mas sim [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (basta mudar de `()` para `[]`):
>
> `numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)]`

Onde `n` é a quantidade de números a ser gerado. Perceba que se fizer `print(numbers)`, a saída será:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at ...>
```

Ou seja, a lista propriamente dita ainda não foi gerada. Mesmo assim, para obter a soma dos valores, basta utilizar a função nativa `sum`:

```
total = sum(numbers)
```

Fazendo `print(total)`, um valor inteiro referente a soma de todos os números é exibida. No meu caso, o total foi de 300.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/I19QE8).

Comment: `random.sample(range(x), x-y)` também serve se não quiseres duplicados

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja apenas `somar` os números que foram gerados de forma aleatória, você pode usar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from random import randint

n = int(input('Desejas gerar quantos números aleatórios? '))
numeros = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)]
soma = sum(numeros)
print(f'\033[32mA soma dos {n} números aleatórios gerados é: {soma}\033[m')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ntlnzlbk-solkarped).

Agora, se você deseja realizar a soma de valores gerados de forma aleatória e sem `repetições` você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from random import sample

n = int(input('Desejas gerar quantos números aleatórios? '))
numeros = sample(range(1, 100), n)
soma = sum(numeros)
print(f'\033[32mA soma dos {n} números aleatórios gerados é: {soma}\033[m')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/npyixmlm-solkarped).

Observe que o método `sample` da classe `random`, realiza sorteios sem repetições.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

n = 2

total = (random.randint(1, 100), n)

a=str(total).split(",")[0].split("(")[1]
b=str(total).split(",")[1].split(")")[0]

soma=int(a) + int(b)

print soma
```